# Nested loops in scala

Tags: scala

I noticed that scala loops differs from java loops:

```
//java:
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
     System.out.println("1loop");
     for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
         System.out.println("2loop");     
     }
}
// output:
1loop
2loop
2loop
...
```

And in `Scala`:

```
ranges.foreach{ range_line =>
      print("1")
      transactions.foreach{ transaction_line =>
        print("2")       
      }
    }
//output 
111...22
```

Why it happening so? How to rearrange this nested loop to more scala-like style?

```
val ranges = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/ranges.tsv")).getLines
val transactions = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/transactions.tsv")).getLines
```

Comment: Can you show what `ranges` and `transactions` are (their types)?

Comment: @Zoltán, I added. They are `Streams`

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just add `toArray` to the end of ranges and transactions initialization. But my be you can suggest me more sophisticated solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `transactions` is not a regular collection like a `List` or `Array` - it is probably a representation of some future computation, e.g. a `Future` or some kind of stream.

If so, the function you pass to `transactions.foreach` is likely to be running asynchronously (i.e. later on, sometimes on a different thread, typically not blocking the calling thread).

Following this assumption, your call to `transactions.foreach` is causing some work to happen "in the background", but the `ranges.foreach` is continuing on, uninterrupted. `ranges.foreach` could potentially finish, then the work triggered by `transactions.foreach` finally gets around to running, so you get all of the `2`'s at the end.

---

That said, this appears to be an abnormal case. If `ranges` and `transactions` were regular collections like a `List`, you'd see the same looping behavior as you would with a regular Java collection.

Comment: Thanks, Dylan! You are right! This is streams. I fixed it by add `asArray`. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely some issue with your definitions for `ranges` and `transactions`, please do not that `foreach` call is not equivalent to Java's `for-loop`, `foreach` intends to iterate over the collection. If you try to following snippet, which in some sense equivalent to the `for-loop` of your, then you'll see the desired result:

```
    scala> 

    (1 to 2).foreach { i1 =>
      println("1loop")
      (1 to 2).foreach { i2 =>
        println("2loop")
      }
    }

    1loop
    2loop
    2loop
    1loop
    2loop
    2loop
```

Hope it helps